# ortools Dependency updates Abseil-cpp

Tags: or-tools

Dears,
in the release note of the last ortools version I see that it is required:
Dependency updates
Abseil-cpp b832dce updated to c51510d (LTS 20200225.2).

What should I have to do to use it? I'm working in on Windows in python with a venv.
Sorry for the trivial question but it is not clear to me how to update it.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I believe it shouldn't matter to you unless you are compiling from source

Comment: no i'm not compiling...so nothing to do! thanks